# How to let Laravel know it's AJAX request without jQuery

Tags: ajax, laravel

There is a parameter in jQuery $.ajax() function called 'dataType', which i could set to 'json' so Laravel will response json even if validation is failed. So how to get that effect with pure js. I was trying to set header like this: 
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
Here full code:
    var xhr =  new XMLHttpRequest();

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4){
        console.log(this.response);
    }
}   
csrf = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-
token"]').getAttribute('content');
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('text','Funy story');

xhr.open('POST','/posttest/',true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN',csrf);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
```

Comment: Use your browser dev tools, inspect the jQuery request, and find out what headers it is sending. Then adapt your code.

Comment: Thank You. It has ' X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'  header. It works.